# How to obtain invite link from telegram if I'm already added to the group without asking the admin?

Tags: hyperlink, telegram, invite

As described in the title, I'm already in a private channel but I don't have an invite link. How can I get one without asking the admin?

I try looking at this forum and get a chat id but chat id and channel are different